# PHP's nl2br is not working correctly

Tags: php, carriage-return

For example, I have:

```
Lorem Ipsum

Dolor Sir Amet
```

As the content of `$s`. Now if I print the result of `htmlspecialchars(nl2br($s))` is:

```
Lorem Ipsum<br />
<br />
Dolor Sir Amet
```

While the result I want is:

```
Lorem Ipsum<br /><br /> Dolor Sir Amet
```

Why the `nl2br` is not removing the carriage return even though it's already inserting the `<br />` ? Or how is the correct usage of `nl2br` to correctly remove the carriage return? Because this breaks my SQL. I'm running PHP on Apache in Windows 7. Thanks.

Comment: nl2br ___does___ remove the newline (though it won't necessarily replace a return character)

Comment: there is a missing `s` characer of you `htmlspecialchars` function.

Comment: @MarkBaker yes it's supposed to be like that. But that is the result I got. I don't know why.

Comment: @lolka_bolka oh you're right. But don't worry, my code in the project is already correct. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to replace all linebreaks to `<br />` you should use an extended function, 
here it is an example:

```
<?php 
function nl2br2($string) { 
$string = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), "<br />", $string); 
return $string; 
}
```

Each OS have different ASCII chars for linebreak:
 
windows = \r\n 
unix = \n 
mac = \r

Comment: Oh okay, let me try it. :)